# Nicer way to not mach a pattern in autocmd

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

I want to to run run an autocmd for all but tex files, i figured out this solution:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.[^t][^e][^x] :Autoformat
```

but is kind of ugly, because of this repeated [^..] pattern. Is there a nicer wy?

Comment: It's not only ugly, but wrong: it won't trigger on e.g. `foo.txt`. The correct negation of `*.tex` is `{*[^.]???,*[^t]??,*[^e]?,*[^x]}`

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to do this is to call a function for each file and in the function check, return if the file extension is of a certain type. 
I have explained similar alternatives[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28838030/789222)

The disadvantage of your example is, your pattern won't trigger for files like foobar.txt (first t will be excluded), files without extensions, foobar.diff (extension too long).